# Why can I not use SSL certificate from TeamCity Agent?

Tags: ssl-certificate, teamcity

We have a tool that we need to integrate in our automated build process (we use TeamCity for our automated builds). The tool talks to a WCF web service that is configured for SSL certificate authentication.

I have searched around to see how this can be done in TeamCity. Unfortunately all I've found seems to be authentication between TeamCity Server and clients or plugins.

How can I consume a certificate in my machine certificates store if a running TeamCity agent as a Local System account for example. It seems when running it in this account, it does not have access to the certificates.

Thanks in advance for your help guys.

Comment: From experience It's not a good idea to use Local System account for your build agent. You will have problems accessing network shares. use dedicated user that you can fine tune manually for access rights and other configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from the fact that Local System Account can not find the certificated installed by other users on the machine.

You can [install a system wide certificate](https://superuser.com/questions/370217/trust-ssl-certificate-to-local-system-account) Or you can run a command line under Local System Account and install the required certificate.

You can use psexec from [SysInternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/sysinternals) suit to get the command line

```
psexec -i -s cmd.exe
```

And install the certificate from [command line](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732061%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Comment: I ended up installing a system wide certificate from a system context command line started using psexec tool. Thanks Mehran!